# perl regex in php - weird non repeating regex error

Tags: php, regex

In search of a good url validation regex, helped by older stackoverflow posts, I found this link

http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

from which I took the last (and best one):

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

And I passed it to a php function:

```
function isURLValid($s) {
    $regexp = '_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS';

    $r = preg_match($regexp, $s);
    if ($r === 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Initially, wanting to do some tests I got errors:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \\L, \\l, \\N{name}, \\U, or \\u at offset 318 in /home/path/functions.php on line 4
```

I came to understand that there is a difference between perl and pcre(php) regexes and started looking around for a conversion tool but did not find any.

Some minutes later and WITHOUT MAKING ANY CHANGES, the function works properly and doesn't throw up any errors any more.

1- How is that even possible (not getting any more notices) ?

2- Now that it works, do I need to convert it to PCRE format just to be sure? If yes, how ? I'm a novice at regexes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think PHP normally requires backslashes at either end of your regex pattern

Comment: @scrowler: -1. it requires DELIMETERS. doesn't matter what the char is, as long as the first/last chars of the pattern are the same. e.g. `'#foo#'` and `'/foo/'` are the exact same as far as preg is concerned.

Comment: @MarcB if I add a # in both the beginning and the end of it, I get the following error: 

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 332

Comment: Probably this: `\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}`. You're forcing PHP to generate a list of around ~65,000 chars to include into that char class.

Comment: @MarcB is there a reason that it works even without the # ?

Comment: # is just an example. In your copy-pastaed version, `_` is the delimeter, and the `iuS` at the end are extra flags. i = case insensitive, u = enable unicode, S = pre-compile pattern for later reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex string you posted is valid in PCRE.

I don't see any problems here.